# применение перегрузки оператора + с использованием указателя C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, перегрузка-операторов

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся в одной задаче с перегрузкой операторов, в моем случае первым было сложение + для двух матриц. Я не смог сложить два объекта, объявленных с применением указателя и оператора new. Выводилась ошибка что-то вроде выражение должно относиться к целочисленному типу...

```
Matrix* matrixPA = new Matrix(3,3);
Matrix* matrixPB = new Matrix(3,3);
Matrix* matrixPC = new Matrix(3,3);
matrixPC = matrixPA + matrixPB;// запись 1
// если я делал вот так matrixPC = matrixPA->operator+(matrixPB);-код 
//работал, но хотелось бы чтобы было как в записи 1
...
Matrix Matrix::operator+(Matrix* matrix)
{
    return *sum(matrix);
}

Matrix Matrix::operator=(Matrix* matrix)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < stolb; j++)
        {
            this->matrix[i][j] = matrix->matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Функция `sum:`

```
Matrix Matrix::sum(Matrix* matrix)
{
    if (matrix.str == this->str && matrix.stolb == this->stolb) {
        Matrix *matrixC = new Matrix(str, stolb);
        for (size_t i(0); i < this->str; i++)
            for (size_t j(0); j < this->stolb; j++)
                matrixC->matrix[i][j] = this->matrix[i][j] + matrix->matrix[i][j];
        return *matrixC;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Матрицы должны быть одинаковых размерностей!" << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

Но если дело обстоит так,

```
Matrix matrixPA(3, 3);
Matrix matrixPB (3, 3);
Matrix matrixPC(3, 3);
matrixPC = matrixPA + matrixPB;
...
Matrix Matrix::operator+(Matrix& matrix)
{
    return sum(matrix);
}

Matrix Matrix::operator=(Matrix& matrix)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < stolb; j++)
        {
            this->matrix[i][j] = matrix.matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Функция `sum:`

```
    Matrix Matrix::sum(Matrix& matrix)
{
    if (matrix.str == this->str && matrix.stolb == this->stolb) {
        Matrix matrixC(str, stolb);
        for (size_t i(0); i < this->str; i++)
            for (size_t j(0); j < this->stolb; j++)
                matrixC.matrix[i][j] = this->matrix[i][j] + matrix.matrix[i][j];
        return matrixC;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Матрицы должны быть одинаковых размерностей!" << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

то все работает. Почему??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотите складывать два указателя, но оператор-то имеет вид

```
Matrix Matrix::operator=(Matrix* matrix)
```

Как минимум вам нужно использовать

```
*matrixPA + matrixPB
```

или

```
matrixPA->operator+(matrixPB)
```

Потому что иначе компилятор не понимает, что вам нужно: у вас есть только оператор `Matrix& + *Matrix`, грубо говоря... При перегрузке операторов по меньшей мере один аргумент должен быть объектом класса.

Но оно и хорошо, что у вас ничего не получается: это очень нездоровая мысль - переопределять сложение указателей. Кроме того, как вы себе представляете дальнейшее развитие событий:

```
matrixPC = matrixPA + matrixPB;
```

Указатель получает *что*? Присваиваете указателю новую матрицу? При этом теряя старое значение? И, кстати, возвращенная вашим оператором матрица ведет к утечке памяти - вы просто теряете указатель на создаваемую в операторе матрицу. Так что С++, мешая вам сделать то, что вы хотите, уже обезопасил вас от массы неприятностей :)

Ну, а почему работает второй код? Потому что он правильно написан.

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что данный оператор присваивания

```
Matrix Matrix::operator=(Matrix* matrix)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < stolb; j++)
        {
            this->matrix[i][j] = matrix->matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

некорректный, так как в общем случае две матрицы могут иметь различные значения для полей `str` и `stolb`. Поэтому циклы внутри оператора могут привести к обращению к памяти, которая не принадлежит выделенным динамически массивам.

Вам следует, во-первых, переопределить копирующий оператор присваивания, так как данный оператор, показанный выше, не является таковым. Фактически, это оператор присваивания указателя объекту класса. Компилятор неявно для вас определит копирующий оператор присваивания, который будет копировать объекты по-членно, что в результате может быть совсем не то, что вы ожидали.

Поэтому вместо данного оператора, который присваивает указатель вам надо определить копирующий оператор присваивания, объявление которого будет выглядеть следующим образом

```
Matrix ? Matrix::operator =( const Matrix &matrix );
```

Либо совсем запретить присваивание, определив оператор как удаленный

```
Matrix ? Matrix::operator =( const Matrix &matrix ) = delete;
```

Что касается вами приведенных фрагментов кода, то в этом фрагменте

```
Matrix* matrixPA = new Matrix(3,3);
Matrix* matrixPB = new Matrix(3,3);
Matrix* matrixPC = new Matrix(3,3);
matrixPC = matrixPA + matrixPB;// запись 1
```

все три переменные являются указателями, и вы пытаетесь сложить два указателя. Однако такая операция для указателей в языке не определена.

Интерфейс данной функции

```
Matrix Matrix::sum(Matrix* matrix)
{
    if (matrix.str == this->str && matrix.stolb == this->stolb) {
        Matrix *matrixC = new Matrix(str, stolb);
        for (size_t i(0); i < this->str; i++)
            for (size_t j(0); j < this->stolb; j++)
                matrixC->matrix[i][j] = this->matrix[i][j] + matrix->matrix[i][j];
        return *matrixC;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Матрицы должны быть одинаковых размерностей!" << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

также некорректный. Функция должна выбрасывать исключение, а не возвращать копию
текущего объекта если размерности матриц не совпадают. К тому же происходит утечка памяти, так как внутри функции вы динамически создали объект, а затем возвращаете копию этого объекта, а память для изначально созданного объекта не удаляется, и доступа к указателю будет потерн.

Вам следует перегружать операторы для объектов, а не указателей на них.

Также имейте в виду, если внутри класса вы динамически выделяете память, то вы обязаны определить в явном виде по крайней мере конструктор копирования, копирующий оператор присваивания и деструктор.

Comment: последовал Вашему совету.

Comment: @СемёнШелухин И правильно сделали.:)